# TEX filter in Moodle merging overlines

Tags: moodle, tex

I am currently using the TEX filter to write some digital logic expressions in Moodle and am running in to a significant issue.

If I write $$ \overline{A}\overline{B}\overline{C} $$, the filter displays the overlines as a single overline instead of three separate overlines. Inserting individual spaces does not seem to work either.

It doesn't seem to be a typeface issue; I changed to a bold math typeface and the same issue appears.

Is there a way to insert a hard space between characters in TEX math? Or a way to split the overlines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@MLAU Fractions in TeX are actually simple, as long as you remember the rules.
 $$ \frac{numerator}{denominator} $$ which produces [image]